# Terraform Databricks AWS instance profile - "authentication is not configured for provider"

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, databricks, terraform-provider-databricks

I'm trying to create a databricks instance profile using the sample code from the [documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/databrickslabs/databricks/latest/docs/resources/instance_profile).

Terraform can generate the plan successfully but when I try to apply it it gives me this error:

```
╷
│ Error: cannot create instance profile: authentication is not configured for provider.. Please check https://registry.terraform.io/providers/databrickslabs/databricks/latest/docs#authentication for details
│
│   with databricks_instance_profile.shared,
│   on IAM.tf line 73, in resource "databricks_instance_profile" "shared":
│   73: resource "databricks_instance_profile" "shared" {
```

I have setup username/password authentication for databricks in my terraform tfvars files and this works - it is able to actually provision a workspace, but fails when creating the instance profile.

Appreciate any inputs on what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Suspect this to be AWS auth issue, Did you setup AWS creds in ~/.aws/credentials and use it while provisioning TF stack. can you share your template to check the issue. further

Comment: @omuthu, this isn't an auth issue. I can launch other resources from the same templates using terraform.

Answer (score 1):

Usually this kind of problems arise when you create a workspace & attempt to use it in the same terraform template.  The solution for that is to have two declarations of the Databricks provider - one will be used for creation of the workspace, and second - for creation of the objects inside workspace. The [AWS provisioning guide](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/databrickslabs/databricks/latest/docs/guides/aws-workspace) is a part of official documentation and contains full example:

```
provider "databricks" {
  alias    = "mws"
  host     = "https://accounts.cloud.databricks.com"
  username = var.databricks_account_username
  password = var.databricks_account_password
}

# Notice "provider = databricks.mws" !
resource "databricks_mws_credentials" "this" {
  provider         = databricks.mws
  account_id       = var.databricks_account_id
  role_arn         = aws_iam_role.cross_account_role.arn
  credentials_name = "${local.prefix}-creds"
  depends_on       = [aws_iam_role_policy.this]
}

provider "databricks" {
  host  = var.databricks_host
  token = var.databricks_token
}

resource "databricks_instance_profile" "shared" {
  depends_on = [databricks_mws_workspaces.this]
  instance_profile_arn = aws_iam_instance_profile.shared.arn
}
```

Another common issue arises from the fact that Terraform is trying to run as many tasks as possible in parallel, so it may attempt to create Terraform resource before workspace is created - this is [explicitly documented](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/databrickslabs/databricks/latest/docs/guides/aws-workspace#data-resources-and-authentication-is-not-configured-errors) in the AWS provisioning guide, so you need to add `depends_on = [databricks_mws_workspaces.this]` to all databricks resources, so Terraform won't attempt to create Databricks objects before creating workspace:

P.S. It's also recommended to upgrade to the latest version of provider (0.4.4 as of right now) that has better error messages for such problems.

Comment: Thanks, Alex. I tried this and tried this and it got me past the original error but falter on another one:

```Error: cannot create instance profile: Databricks API (/api/2.0/instance-profiles/add) requires you to set `host` property (or DATABRICKS_HOST env variable) to result of `databricks_mws_workspaces.this.workspace_url`. This error may happen if you're using provider in both normal and multiworkspace mode. Please refactor your code into different modules.
```
... to be continued

Comment: ... continued:

```Runnable example that we use for integration testing can be found in this repository at https://registry.terraform.io/providers/databrickslabs/databricks/latest/docs/guides/aws-workspace
```
I've split the workspace creation and instance profile creation part into different modules, the host value is set and exported as an output and I've added it as a shell env variable too. But I keep getting the same error.

Comment: Also, now the workspace already exists and I'm just trying to add the instance profile - should it still be failing a dependency check?

Comment: If you use two modules, then you need to set dependency between them. Even if workspace exists, this information may read from state after terraform attempts to create an instance profile. Unfortunately, this is a normal Terraform behavior with parallel execution, etc., and it's impossible to set `depends_on` on the provider level