# Error: Databricks API requires you to set `host` property

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, databricks, terraform-provider-databricks

Related question: [Terraform Databricks AWS instance profile - "authentication is not configured for provider"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70647230/terraform-databricks-aws-instance-profile-authentication-is-not-configured-fo/)

After resolving the error in that question and proceeding, I have started encountering the following error on multiple different operations (create databricks instance profile, query terraform databricks data sources like `databricks_current_user` or `databricks_spark_version`) etc:

`` Error: cannot create instance profile: Databricks API (/api/2.0/instance-profiles/add) requires you to set `host` property (or DATABRICKS_HOST env variable) to result of `databricks_mws_workspaces.this.workspace_url`. This error may happen if you're using provider in both normal and multiworkspace mode. Please refactor your code into different modules. Runnable example that we use for integration testing can be found in this repository at https://registry.terraform.io/providers/databrickslabs/databricks/latest/docs/guides/aws-workspace ``

I am able to create an instance profile manually in the Databricks workspace admin console and am able to create clusters and run notebooks in it.

Relevant code:

```
main.tf:
module "create-workspace" {
  source = "./modules/create-workspace"

  env     = var.env
  region  = var.region
  databricks_host = var.databricks_host
  databricks_account_username = var.databricks_account_username
  databricks_account_password = var.databricks_account_password
  databricks_account_id = var.databricks_account_id
}

providers-main.tf:
terraform {
  required_version = ">= 1.1.0"

    required_providers {
        databricks = {
            source  = "databrickslabs/databricks"
            version = "0.4.4"
        }
        aws = {
            source = "hashicorp/aws"
            version = ">= 3.49.0"
        }
    }
}

provider "aws" {
  region = var.region
  profile = var.aws_profile
}

provider "databricks" {
  host  = var.databricks_host
  token = var.databricks_manually_created_workspace_token
}

modules/create-workspace/providers.tf:
terraform {
  required_version = ">= 1.1.0"

    required_providers {
        databricks = {
            source  = "databrickslabs/databricks"
            version = "0.4.4"
        }
        aws = {
            source = "hashicorp/aws"
            version = ">= 3.49.0"
        }
    }
}

provider "aws" {
  region = var.region
  profile = var.aws_profile
}

provider "databricks" {
  host  = var.databricks_host
  # token = var.databricks_manually_created_workspace_token - doesn't make a difference switching from username/password to token
  username = var.databricks_account_username
  password = var.databricks_account_password
  account_id = var.databricks_account_id
}

provider "databricks" {
  alias    = "mws"
  # host     = 
  username = var.databricks_account_username
  password = var.databricks_account_password
  account_id = var.databricks_account_id
}

modules/create-workspace/databricks-workspace.tf:
resource "databricks_mws_credentials" "this" {
  provider         = databricks.mws
  account_id       = var.databricks_account_id
  role_arn         = aws_iam_role.cross_account_role.arn
  credentials_name = "${local.prefix}-creds"
  depends_on       = [aws_iam_role_policy.this]
}

resource "databricks_mws_workspaces" "this" {
  provider        = databricks.mws
  account_id      = var.databricks_account_id
  aws_region      = var.region
  workspace_name  = local.prefix
  deployment_name = local.prefix

  credentials_id           = databricks_mws_credentials.this.credentials_id
  storage_configuration_id = databricks_mws_storage_configurations.this.storage_configuration_id
  network_id               = databricks_mws_networks.this.network_id

}

modules/create-workspace/IAM.tf:
data "databricks_aws_assume_role_policy" "this" {
  external_id = var.databricks_account_id
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "cross_account_role" {
  name               = "${local.prefix}-crossaccount"
  assume_role_policy = data.databricks_aws_assume_role_policy.this.json
}

resource "time_sleep" "wait" {
  depends_on = [
  aws_iam_role.cross_account_role]
  create_duration = "10s"
}

data "databricks_aws_crossaccount_policy" "this" {}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy" "this" {
  name   = "${local.prefix}-policy"
  role   = aws_iam_role.cross_account_role.id
  policy = data.databricks_aws_crossaccount_policy.this.json
}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "pass_role_for_s3_access" {
  statement {
    effect    = "Allow"
    actions   = ["iam:PassRole"]
    resources = [aws_iam_role.cross_account_role.arn]
  }
}

resource "aws_iam_policy" "pass_role_for_s3_access" {
  name   = "databricks-shared-pass-role-for-s3-access"
  path   = "/"
  policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.pass_role_for_s3_access.json
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "cross_account" {
  policy_arn = aws_iam_policy.pass_role_for_s3_access.arn
  role       = aws_iam_role.cross_account_role.name
}

resource "aws_iam_instance_profile" "shared" {
  name = "databricks-shared-instance-profile"
  role = aws_iam_role.cross_account_role.name
}

resource "databricks_instance_profile" "shared" {
  instance_profile_arn = aws_iam_instance_profile.shared.arn
  depends_on = [databricks_mws_workspaces.this]
}
```

Comment: Without the code we can't help you a lot.

Comment: as it was mentioned in the answer that you linked, you have concurrency issue - you need to use `depends_on` on resources if you're mixing databricks resources & databricks_mws resources in the same module/template

Comment: @MarkoE added code.

Comment: @AlexOtt I am using `depends_on` but it's not making a difference. I've edited the question and added all the relevant terraform code to it, maybe that can help spot what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: it's better to pass providers explicitly to modules. Also, inside the module, provider isn't declared correctly.

Comment: @AlexOtt sorry I don't understand passing providers explicitly to modules - can you please elaborate on that part? Also, can you please point out what is the error in the provider declaration? I see I was missing the host but adding that makes no difference to the result.

Comment: you need to have two providers - one with account ID, username & password - that is used for provisioning of workspace. and another - with workspace URL & personal access token - it will be used for provisioning of resources inside Databricks. In your case, you have both with account_id + username/password

Comment: Thanks, @AlexOtt . That makes sense now. I was able to resolve the issue with this approach. Please add this as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, the problem is that you need to have two Databricks providers:

1. for provisioning of the Databricks workspace itself - it uses Account ID, username and password
2. for provisioning of resources inside the Databricks workspace - it uses host & token

One of these providers needs to be declared with alias so Terraform can distinguish one from another. Documentation for Databricks provider [shows how to do that](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/databrickslabs/databricks/latest/docs/guides/aws-workspace).  But the problem is that Terraform tries to apply all changes in parallel as much as possible, because it doesn't know about dependencies between resources, until you explicitly use `depends_on`, and tries to create Databricks resources before it knows about host value for Databricks workspace (even if it's already created).

Unfortunately, it's not possible to put `depends_on` into the provider block.  So current recommendation to avoid such problem is to to split code into several modules:

1. Module that creates a Databricks workspace and returns host & token
2. Module that creates Databricks objects with provider initialized from received host/token

Also, [Terraform doc recommends](https://www.terraform.io/language/modules/develop/providers) that initialization of providers didn't happen in modules - it's better to declare all providers with aliases inside the top-level template, and pass providers to modules explicitly (see example below). In this case module should have only declaration of required modules, but not their configuration.

For example, top-level template could look like this:

```
terraform {
  required_version = ">= 1.1.0"

    required_providers {
        databricks = {
            source  = "databrickslabs/databricks"
            version = "0.4.5"
        }
    }
}

provider "databricks" {
  host  = var.databricks_host
  token = var.token
}

provider "databricks" {
  alias    = "mws"
  host     = "https://accounts.cloud.databricks.com"
  username = var.databricks_account_username
  password = var.databricks_account_password
  account_id = var.databricks_account_id
}

module "workspace" {
  source    = "./workspace"
  providers = {
    databricks = databricks.workspace  
}}


module "databricks" {
  depends_on = [ module.workspace ]
  source    = "./databricks"
  # No provider block required as we're using default provider
}
```

and module itself like this:

```
terraform {
  required_version = ">= 1.1.0"

    required_providers {
        databricks = {
            source  = "databrickslabs/databricks"
            version = ">= 0.4.4"
        }
    }
}

resource "databricks_cluster" {
...
}
```